# chrome tab focus index API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I use `chrome api` tabs to open multiple links at once.

But the problem is the last link open (or focus) first.

```
$scope.data = [{
    "url":"http://www.google.com"
},{
    "url":"http://www.bing.com"
},{
     "url":"http://www.yahoo.com"
}];

angular.forEach($scope.data, function(data){
    chrome.tabs.create({
        url: data.url
    });
});
```

It's not suitable to do reserve loop because the arrangement of the tabs will be messed up. I think I should use this https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-update but I've no idea how to do it. Help.

Answer (score 2):

The method `chrome.tabs.create` allows you to specify whether the new tab should become active.   Here is a sample code that keeps the first of several opened tabs  active:

```
for (var i=0; i<urlArray.length; i++) {
  chrome.tabs.create({
        url: urlArray[i],
        active: i==0
    }); 
}
```

The above was written after [Xan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/934239/xan)'s suggestion; the older version with `chrome.tabs.update` follows.

---

The `update` method can also be used to change the active tab:

```
chrome.tabs.update(id, {active: true});
```

makes active the tab with given id. Just for demonstration, the following would work with your code:

```
chrome.tabs.query({url: $scope.data[0]}, function(tabsArray) {
  chrome.tabs.update(tabsArray[0].id, {active: true});  
});
```

but it is much better to keep record of tab ids as you create them, not query for them later. To do that, you'd need to provide a callback function with your `chrome.tabs.create` command, which will receive the parameters of the created tab, including its id.

Comment: Actually.. You don't need `update` for that. `active` is a valid parameter for `create`

Comment: Thanks for `chrome.tabs.update(id, {active: true});` - very useful :)